# Visual doesn't update information from a SQL Server table?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

So, I have these insert code in my Visual Studio project which is connected to a SQL Server database:

```
Function insercionRed(ByVal NombRed As String, ByVal Contraseña As String, ByVal RedID As Integer, ByVal ContraseñaAdmin As String) As String

        Dim resultado As String = ""

        Try
            enunciado = New SqlCommand("insert into TablaRed(NombreRed, Contraseña, RedID, ContraseñaAdmin) values('" & NombRed & "','" & Contraseña & "'," & RedID & ",'" & ContraseñaAdmin & "' )", conexiones)
            enunciado.ExecuteNonQuery()
            resultado = "Los datos han sido ingresados exitosamente."
            conexiones.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            resultado = "No se han podido ingresar los datos, intentelo nuevamente."
            conexiones.Close()

        End Try
        Return resultado
    End Function
```

And it works perfectly, it adds the information into my SQL database, but when I try to login immediately after with the new data in these Form: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQFH4.png)

I get the following error, as if it hasn't been updated in my database: [Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K4y0.png)

Is there any solution to this?